# Contagem em PHP através do valor da variável

Tags: php, laravel

Estou com dificuldade em algo relativamente simples, mas está me causando uma dor de cabeça porque sempre pego erro.

Em uma aplicação preciso pegar a quantidade turmas abertas vindo do Crud de Turmas. 
Era para mostrar a quantidade turmas com status em aberto que no caso são 6, porém não estou conseguindo implementar isso para aparecer no dashboard. Só consigo setar o valor de forma manual, nesse exemplo coloquei como 40, alguém pode me ajudar?

Tela:

[image: Tela para o usuário]

E aqui o trecho do código:

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')
<div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-6 col-xs-12">
          <!-- small box -->
          <div class="small-box bg-yellow">
            <div class="inner">
              <h3>40</h3>

              <p>Turmas Abertas</p>
            </div>
            <div class="icon">
              <i class="ion ion-person-add"></i>
            </div>
            <a href="treinamentos" class="small-box-footer">Veja Mais <i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-right"></i></a>
          </div>
    </div>

<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="panel panel-default">

                <div class="panel-heading">Turmas com status <strong>Aberta</strong></div>

                <div class="panel-body table-responsive">
                    <table class="table table-bordered table-striped ajaxTable">
                        <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th><center> @lang('Nome do Treinamento')</th> 
                            <th><center> @lang('Data de Inicio')</th> 
                            <th><center> @lang('Data de Conclusão ')</th> 
                            <th><center> @lang('Situação da Turma')</th> 
                            <th>Ações<center>&nbsp;</th>
                        </tr>
                        </thead>
                        @foreach($treinamentos as $treinamento)
                            @if($treinamento->situacao_turma == "Aberta")
                            <tr>

                                <td><center> ? </td>
                                <td><center>{{ $treinamento->data_inicio }} </td> 
                                <td><center>{{ $treinamento->data_conclusao }} </td> 
                                <td><center>{{ $treinamento->situacao_turma  }} </td>
                                <td><center>

                                    @can('treinamento_view')
                                    <a href="{{ route('admin.treinamentos.show',[$treinamento->id]) }}" class="btn btn-xs btn-primary">@lang('quickadmin.qa_view')</a>
                                    @endcan
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        @endif
                        @endforeach
                    </table>
                </div>
            </div>
</div>

@endsection
```

Imagem:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

CÓDIGO CONTROLLER:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Http\Requests;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class HomeController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('auth');
    }

    /**
     * Show the application dashboard.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index()
    {

        $cargos = \App\Cargo::latest()->get(); 
        $setores = \App\Setore::latest()->get(); 
        $turmas = \App\Turma::latest()->get(); 
        $treinamentos = \App\Treinamento::latest()->get(); 

        return view('home', compact( 'cargos', 'setores', 'turmas', 'treinamentos' ));
    }
}
```

Comment: Eu tenho turmas, com status abertas e planejadas. Queria pegar somente as turmas que estão com status de aberta na variável $situacao_turma e exibir a quantidade total no dashboard

Comment: Eu entendi Allan, mas faz isso > `print_r($treinamentos)` só para eu ver esse objeto.

Comment: Retornou na tela exatamente o: 'print_r($treinamentos)', era isso ou estou fazendo algo errado?

Comment: Tenta assim: `{{print_r($treinamentos)}}`

Comment: Dessa forma ele me retornou todos os registros que tenho cadastrados na minha tabela turmas, nem deu para postar aqui porque excede o limite de caracteres

Comment: Posta os registros na pergunta, edita ela... e posta lá

Comment: editei e coloquei os registros

Comment: Blz, vou dar uma olhada

Comment: Te agradeço por estar me ajudando

Comment: Acho que descobri. vamos ter que testar.

Comment: Massa, estou on

Comment: Apague a lista de você postou!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Após esclarecimento de dúvidas, cheguei a essa resposta:

No seu Controller você fará a contagem para obter o total:

```
public function index()
    {

        $cargos = \App\Cargo::latest()->get(); 
        $setores = \App\Setore::latest()->get(); 
        $turmas = \App\Turma::latest()->get(); 
        $treinamentos = \App\Treinamento::latest()->get(); 
          $total = 0;
          foreach($treinamentos as $treinamento)
            if($treinamento->situacao_turma == "Aberta") $total++;

        return view('home', compact( 'cargos', 'setores', 'turmas', 'treinamentos', 'total' ));
    }
```

Depois é só inseri-lo na view:

```
<h3>{{ $total }}</h3>
```

O restante do código é o mesmo.

Comment: Te agradeço pelo empenho em ajudar. Irei fazer os testes.

Comment: @AllanSampaio mas não a coloque como certa ainda! Tem que ver se é isso mesmo!

Comment: Ok, irei testar e retorno o feedback

Comment: @AllanSampaio você precisa criar esse array de objetos antes de entrar na view! usando o `toArray()`

Comment: Acho que entendi, vou aplicar.

Comment: @AllanSampaio tenta usar no Controller, acho que é o ideal.

Comment: coloquei no controller, estou pegando esse erro agora: 

Undefined variable: treinamento

Mas já ficou mais claro para tentar achar uma solução, continuar tentando aqui. Muito obrigado.

Comment: @AllanSampaio você precisa usar a variável que você usou para criar o array de objetos, entendeu?

Comment: @AllanSampaio tive uma ideia melhor, calma ae

Comment: @AllanSampaio faz o teste agora. Ve se da certo. Fiz uma edição.

Comment: Fiz uma edição na minha pergunta e adicionei uma imagem do meu código do controller, está correto?

Comment: @AllanSampaio ... Não... Não use aquela linha. Use apenas a segunda parte. Fiz uma edição nela que acredito que irá dar certo.

Comment: Mostrou todos os registros no dashboard.

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/87102/discussion-between-andrei-coelho-and-allan-sampaio).